# I have an undeclared identifier error, that I can't figure out

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I can not figure out why this won't work. When I run it I get all kinds of undeclared identifier errors on my object c1 and customer. If i do a Customer* c1 = new Customer(); I still get the same errors and it will not let me setcustomerID. its probably something stupid, Any input would be awesome.

```
void checkout(){

    srand(time(NULL));
    int random = rand() % 3 + 1;

    Customer c1;
    c1.setcustomerID("0");
}




class Customer{
public:
    string customerID;
    string list;
public:
    Customer(){}
    ~Customer(){}



    string getcustomerID(){
        return customerID;
    }
    string getList(){
        return list;
    }
    void setcustomerID(string x){
        customerID = x;
    }
    void setList(int x){
        if(x==1)
            list = "bread";
        if(x==2)
            list = "eggs";
        if(x==3)
            list = "cheese";
    }

};
```

Comment: you shall declare `class Customer;` in front of checkout() function

Comment: You can avoid this headache by splitting your code into two files: a header file and a source file. You should research how to do this on your own. If you get stuck, feel free to come back and ask more questions. Just be sure to show us what you have learned in your research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put:

```
class Customer{
```

before your checkout() method

Comment: You are awesome!! I should have seen that. Thanks for helping me out!